# hibernate. many to many between three tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

**Hello all**

Today I faced some trouble...
I have 3 tables with **many to many** relationship between each. See link below

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pGHR.png)

Below short definition of Entities:
Branchs

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "systembranches")
public class Systembranches {
    private long id;
    ...
    private Set<Systemusers> systemuserses;
    private Set<Userroles> userroleses;
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "branchroles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "BranchId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "UserId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false))
    public Set<Systemusers> getSystemuserses() {
        return systemuserses;
    }

    public void setSystemuserses(Set<Systemusers> users) {
        this.systemuserses = users;
    }

    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "systembranches")
    public Set<Userroles> getUserroleses() {
        return userroleses;
    }

    public void setUserroleses(Set<Userroles> userroleses) {
        this.userroleses = userroleses;
    }
}
```

Users

```
@Entity
public class Systemusers {
    private long id;
    ...
    private Set<Userroles> userroles;
    private Set<Systembranches> systembrancheses;
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "branchroles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "UserId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "RoleId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false))
    public Set<Userroles> getUserroles() {
        return userroles;
    }

    public void setUserroles(Set<Userroles> roles) {
        this.userroles = roles;
    }

    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "systemuserses")
    public Set<Systembranches> getSystembranches() {
        return systembrancheses;
    }

    public void setSystembranches(Set<Systembranches> systembrancheses) {
        this.systembrancheses = systembrancheses;
    }

}
```

Roles

```
@Entity
public class Userroles {
    private long id;
    ...
    private Set<Systemusers> systemusers;
    private Set<Systembranches> systembrancheses;

    ...

    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "userroles")
    public Set<Systemusers> getSystemusers() {
        return systemusers;
    }

    public void setSystemusers(Set<Systemusers> systemusers) {
        this.systemusers = systemusers;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "branchroles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "RoleId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "BranchId",
                    referencedColumnName = "Id",
                    nullable = false))
    public Set<Systembranches> getSystembranches() {
        return systembrancheses;
    }

    public void setSystembranches(Set<Systembranches> systembrancheses) {
        this.systembrancheses = systembrancheses;
    }

}
```

As you can see all tables joined through **fourth** table (**branchroles**) that do not have entity in my application.
This table contains the following data:

```
id UserID BranchId RoleId
1    2        3        2
2    3        3        3
3    1        1        4
5    4        2        4
8    5        2        4
9    6        2        2
```

I need to get list of some entities (for example Roles) on depends on two Set<> property inside this entity (`Set<Systemusers>` and `Set<Systembranchs>`)

on SQL it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Userroles r
JOIN branchroles connector ON r.id = connector.RoleId
JOIN systembranches b ON b.id = connector.BranchId
JOIN systemusers u ON u.id = connector.UserId
WHERE u.id = 3 and b.id = 2
```

In my Java code I wrote

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                   .createCriteria(Userroles.class)
                   .createCriteria("systemusers")
                   .add(Restrictions.eq("id", userId))
                   .createCriteria("systembranches")
                   .add(Restrictions.eq("id", branchId))
                   .list();
```

and other similar variants like

```
.createCriteria(Userroles.class, "r")
                   .createCriteria("r.systemusers", "u", JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
```

but each time Hibernate generate code like this

[Hibernate SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsPR0.png)

As you can see in this SQL one extra `JOIN` and as result invalid dependency in next `JOIN` expression

How can I fix it? I want to write code using Criteria API and without one-to-many relationsips and without `branchroles` entity, if it possible. Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are missing something in Your database structure.

If you are looking for Many To Many Relationship it can be Possible between Two table.

One Table will have mapping detail that is your owning table.

If you want to go for three table Many To Many than you need to Consider Your JoinTable as entity table in application.

Than Map it to third Table with Many to Many Relationship.

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for answer.
>> Consider Your JoinTable as entity table in application.
How can it help?